# What's the point in this xor magic defining the upper bound of a loop?

Tags: c#, .net, loops, xor

I've stumbled upon this piece of code without any comments:

```
int delay = 5;
int maxDelay = 5 * (3 ^ 5); // << what's this xor magic?
while( Something && delay < maxDelay ) {
    Thread.Sleep( delay );
    delay *= 3;
}
```

What's the point in that `3 ^ 5`? That's "3 xor 5" which is six, not anything interesting like maybe one third of `Int32.MaxValue`. Why not just write `6` instead? I guess it has to do something with the fact that the result is then multiplied by `5` and also the value is multiplied by `3` on each iteration.

Is that some well-known pattern? What does it do?

Comment: nevermind ya maxDelay could just be 30 in this case seems someone was bored or is one of those mathematical savants that's why the delay is multiplied by 3 at the end of the loop lol, he wanted it to be like delay would be 5.. then 15.. then finally 30 but it still only does 5,15 then 45 probably wanted it to run 3 times instead of 2.

Comment: Yuk. I'd instachange that to something not stupid, i.e. `maxDelay = 30;` Or indeed 243 if he meant to use a power operator.

Comment: Maybe he wanted to do `Math.Pow(3, 5)` and was to lazy to do it with calc (and wrote this without knowing that this is xor)

Comment: Maybe someone not too familiar with C# who thought they were doing 3<sup>5</sup>?

Comment: What @Damien_The_Unbeliever said: Are you sure this is not a bug?

Comment: It makes sense that he meant to use the power operator, what with the delay going up by *3 each time. The whole thing looks a bit stinky though; I bet there's better ways of waiting for the operation to complete.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Surely there are better ways, but don't expect that someone that doesn't know how about xor knows these ways

Comment: I think he thought that `delay *= 3` would always do 5*3=15 but starting the initial counter to begin at 0 so it would still do 0,15,30  or 5,15,30 either way just make it run 3 times.  it's really strange probably more insight could on the sleep timer if you posted the complete while loop why have such strange sleep times

Comment: if its power of `5 * (3 ^ 5)` would be `1215`
which does work well with the delay *= 3 which ends up at `1215` as well
`0,5,15,45,135,405,1215` on the 7th loop

Comment: @codroipo Agreed, but sharptooth probably *does* know better ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He meant `Math.Pow(3, 5)` but `^` is not the power operator (which does not exist in C#). This is a bug.

That makes sense because in the loop he is increasing `delay` exponentially. So the exponential upper bound makes sense.

I think this is bad style even if it worked. It is not obvious how often the loop will run. He should have used a normal for loop and computed `delay` freshly inside the loop instead of running it along the loop incrementally.

Comment: Em... What's the problem with incrementing the delay inside loop?

Comment: It obscures what the value means at each loop iteration. Your intention is that the value is Math.Pow(3, i). Then say so! Don't obfuscate the power operation by computing it through N multiplications. Bad style, hard to follow. Simply `var delay = Math.Pow(3, i);`.